# Prophet Abraham asking Allah to accept their repentance upon completing the House of Allah

Tags: quran, tafseer, tawba, prophet-ibrahim

> Our Lord, and make us Muslims [in submission] to You and from our
> descendants a Muslim nation [in submission] to You. And show us our
> rites and accept our repentance. Indeed, You are the Accepting of
> repentance, the Merciful. [—Baqarah 2:128](http://corpus.quran.com/translation.jsp?chapter=2&verse=128)

Do we know *exactly why* Prophet Abraham is asking Allah to accept their repentance? (Obviously, one can repent anytime, on any occasion, but Allah must have a reason to narrate us this specific occasion; and it is not that Prophet Abraham and and his son Ishmael did something bad; on the contrary, they have just completed the House of Allah.)

Comment: Well I guess that Ibrahim is teaching us here. As we know that a complete hajj would "clean" us from all sins like a sincere repentance would clean us from a specific sin. But Allah knows best.

Answer (score 1):

We don't have any clear evidence like reports from the Prophet (SAW) as far as I could find.

However, many tafasir give these two reasons as possible (beyond the obvious one that they are repenting from their general mistakes):

- They are setting an example for people on what to do near the House of Allah.
- They are seeking forgiveness for their descendants, that were just mentioned in the verse.